# How do I centre my boostrap nav in the center of my background image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, centering

I'm fairly new to web development, can someone please help me resolve this issue with regards to my bootstrap build as it would be much appreciated.

I'm fairly new to web development, can someone please help me resolve this issue with regards to my bootstrap build as it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

```css
/* Global styles */

body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem; 
    
}

/* background image */

.iw-bg-image {
    background-image: url('./image/desktop_hero.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}




/* Navigation */
.my-nav {
    background-color: #e4137fde;
}

/* nav link text hover color */
.nav-link:hover {
  color: #e4137e !important;
}

/* Main header text */
.iw-header {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.btn-background {
    color: white;
    background-color: #e4137fde;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Apollo App.</title>

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,900" rel="stylesheet">
 

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/v4-shims.css">

  

  <!-- Bootstrap CDN and external CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- Main container-->
    <div class="container iw-bg-image nav-position">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

       <!-- Navbar -->
      
       <nav class="navbar my-nav navbar-expand-lg mt-4">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white mb-1 col-9 col-lg-4" href="index.html"><img src="image/sfw_logo.png" width="80%" alt="Student finance wales logo"></a>
        
        <!-- Hamburger menu  -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
        </button>
      
        <!-- Accesibilty - Login - Cymraeg -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link text-white pink-hover" target="_blank" href="accessibilty.html">Accessibility <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="https://logon.slc.co.uk/cas/login?_locale=en_CY">Login/ Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Cymraeg</a>
            </li>

            <!-- Product dropdown -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown pr-2">
              <a class="nav-link text-white dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Products
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Undergraduate Student</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Postgraduate Student</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Parents & partners</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EU Student </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Loan Repayments</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>


  <h1 class="iw-header">Apply Now!</h1>












    <!-- Main container ends-->
    </div>


   

    <!-- Bootstrap's Javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to describe your problem more, instead of copying your one sentence.

Comment: Apologies, I accidentally posted my question and I don't know how to edit the post. Sorry, this is the first time I've used this platform.

Comment: Click on "edit", at the bottom of your question. On the left side, next to your username

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to center horizontally you could do this:

`<nav class="navbar my-nav navbar-expand-lg mt-4 mx-auto">`

`mx-auto` is centering your navigation.

```css
   
/* Global styles */

body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem; 
    
}

/* background image */

.iw-bg-image {
    background-image: url('./image/desktop_hero.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}




/* Navigation */
.my-nav {
    background-color: #e4137fde;
}

/* nav link text hover color */
.nav-link:hover {
  color: #e4137e !important;
}

/* Main header text */
.iw-header {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.btn-background {
    color: white;
    background-color: #e4137fde;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Apollo App.</title>

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,900" rel="stylesheet">
 

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/v4-shims.css">

  

  <!-- Bootstrap CDN and external CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- Main container-->
    <div class="container iw-bg-image nav-position">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

       <!-- Navbar -->
      
       <nav class="navbar my-nav navbar-expand-lg mt-4 mx-auto">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white mb-1 col-9 col-lg-4" href="index.html"><img src="image/sfw_logo.png" width="80%" alt="Student finance wales logo"></a>
        
        <!-- Hamburger menu  -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
        </button>
      
        <!-- Accesibilty - Login - Cymraeg -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link text-white pink-hover" target="_blank" href="accessibilty.html">Accessibility <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="https://logon.slc.co.uk/cas/login?_locale=en_CY">Login/ Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Cymraeg</a>
            </li>

            <!-- Product dropdown -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown pr-2">
              <a class="nav-link text-white dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Products
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Undergraduate Student</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Postgraduate Student</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Parents & partners</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EU Student </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Loan Repayments</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>


  <h1 class="iw-header">Apply Now!</h1>












    <!-- Main container ends-->
    </div>


   

    <!-- Bootstrap's Javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi J4R, Thanks very much. I totally appreciate your help. I tried to apply text-align and various other methods with no luck. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. cheers

Comment: did you try to add `mx-auto` to your `<nav>` element?

Comment: Yes, I added the bootstrap element to the nav and it worked. I'm pretty sure I tried that but I think I applied it to the wrong tag. thanks again.

Comment: I've only just started learning bootstrap so your help is much appreciated

Comment: glad i could help you. Keep coding!